# ngx-bootstrap DatePicker: Use default locale if missing a translation

Tags: ngx-bootstrap

I want to use serbian language in ngx-bootstrap datepicker but as I see it's not supported yet. Is there any way to set up for example "EN" locale if serbian or any other locale missing?